# Django: NoReverseMatch - reverse for '' with arguments '('', '')' not found

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I can't figure out what is causing my `NoReverseMatch` error in django. I've read numerous other questions on SO, and all of the usual suspects do not seem to be a problem in my code. I have defined a namespace in my project urls.py, I've included this in my html template, I've checked my spelling everywhere, and I've made sure that I am passing the right arguments as specified in my apps urls.py. And still it doesn't work! I would be grateful for any help.

**views.py:**

```
from vocab.forms import CustomWordForm
@login_required
def add_custom_word(request, target_word, source_word):
    """
    Add new word
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomWordForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            deck_name = form.cleaned_data['deck']
            source_word = form.cleaned_data['source_word']
            target_word = form.cleaned_data['target_word']
            fluency = form.cleaned_data['fluency']
            user = request.user
            Word.objects.create(user=user, target_word=target_word,
                source_word=source_word, deck_name=deck_name, fluency=fluency)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('vocab:index'))
    if request.method =="GET":
        from vocab.models import Word
        user = request.user
        form = CustomWordForm(initial={'user': user, 'target_word': target_word, 'source_word': source_word, 'deck_name': 'My Words', 'fluency': 0})

    return render(request, 'vocab/add_custom_initial.html', {'form': form})
```

**urls.py:**

```
    app_name='vocab'
    
    urlpatterns = [
    
        path("<str:target_word>/<str:source_word>/", views.add_custom_word, name='song-add'),
    
    ]
```

**html snippet:**

```
   {% elif item.0 in dict_flash %}
          <a href="{% url 'vocab:song-add' target_word=item.0 source_word=item.2 %}">Add</a>
```

**add_custom_initial.html:**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'vocab:song-add' word.target_word word.source_word %}" enctype='multipart/form-data' id="addWordForm">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form form %}
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-success"> <br>
        </form>
```

**forms.py:**

```
class CustomWordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Word
        fields = ("target_word",'source_word', 'fluency','deck_name')
```

This is the error:
`NoReverseMatch at /vocab/воздух/air, veil/ Reverse for 'song-add' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['vocab/(?P<target_word>[^/]+)/(?P<source_word>[^/]+)/$']`

And the full **traceback**:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://dev-lr:8000/vocab/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%85/air,%20veil/

Django Version: 3.0.3
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'rest_framework',
 'bootstrap4',
 'bootstrapform',
 'languages',
 'django_countries',
 'import_export',
 'django_tables2',
 'django_filters',
 'accounts',
 'vocab',
 'flash',
 'api',
 'videos',
 'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\mvren\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\Russki\mysite\templates\base.html, error at line 0
   Reverse for 'song-add' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['vocab/(?P<target_word>[^/]+)/(?P<source_word>[^/]+)/$']
   1 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   2 : {% load static %}
   3 : <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   4 :   <head>
   5 :     <meta charset="utf-8">
   6 :     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   7 :     <title>Linga Russki</title>
   8 : {% comment %} Bootstrap CSS {% endcomment %}
   9 :   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
   10 : {% comment %} Google fonts {% endcomment %}


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\Russki\mysite\vocab\views.py", line 259, in add_custom_word
    return render(request, 'vocab/add_custom_initial.html', {'form': form})
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\myRuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 677, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /vocab/воздух/air, veil/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'song-add' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['vocab/(?P<target_word>[^/]+)/(?P<source_word>[^/]+)/$']
```

Comment: what is the propose of  passing `target_word, source_word` here while creating the Word object ?

Comment: @arjun they are fields in my `Word` model

Comment: @arjun because I want to add them as initial fields in my word creation form